# Extract data from API request in Python

Tags: python, api

I'm currently developing an application that uses the UniFi controller API - in this case I'm using pyunifi.

Whenever I try methods to extract the MAC address I am still getting the whole data payload through.

````
import requests

from pyunifi.controller import Controller

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--controller', default='192.168.0.2', help='the controller address (default "unifi")')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', default='apiadmin', help='the controller username (default("admin")')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', default='apipass', help='the controller password')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--port', default='8443', help='the controller port (default "8443")')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', default='v5', help='the controller base version (default "v5")')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--siteid', default='default', help='the site ID, UniFi >=3.x only (default "default")')
parser.add_argument('-V', '--no-ssl-verify', default=False, action='store_true', help='Don\'t verify ssl certificates')
parser.add_argument('-C', '--certificate', default='', help='verify with ssl certificate pem file')
args = parser.parse_args()

ssl_verify = False

if ssl_verify and len(args.certificate) > 0:
        ssl_verify = False 
        
c = Controller(args.controller, args.username, args.password, args.port, args.version, args.siteid, ssl_verify=ssl_verify)
r.requests = requests.get(c.get_clients()).json()
requests['mac']
print(requests)```

Any help would be greatly appreciated to get me on the right track.
````

Comment: You're putting your decoded JSON into `r.requests`, but `print`ing `requests` - is this intended? Additionally, I don't see where you've defined `r` - your example should result in a `NameError`. Lastly - I wouldn't expect the line `requests['mac']` to do much of anything - is this also intended?

Comment: It's spilling out all the data, not just the and almost like the ```requests['mac']``` line is being ignored, I put r.requests as followed by a guide online for trying to get data extraction to work, apologies this is fairly new grounds to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last few lines don't make very much sense in the context of your requirement to extract MAC addresses:

1. `r.requests` should throw a `NameError`, as you haven't defined `r` anywhere in this script.
2. The line `requests['mac']` doesn't do much of anything. This could very well be a valid reference, but what you're referencing here would be the `mac` property of the `requests` object, which you `import`ed from the standard `requests` library. In other words, this would be far from what you'd expect even if you were to `print` or otherwise process this value, anyway.
3. The call `print(requests)` is "spilling out all the data" because you're `print`ing the entire definition of the `requests` library you imported on line 1.
4. Above all, you don't need to import `requests` as `pyunifi` does this in the background for you. Each of the methods you use to interact with the remote API will abstract this lower-level use of `requests` away from your view, hence it doesn't make sense to wrap any of the method calls in `requests.get()`. You should review the documentation of the library you're using (and the source code, if you so desire) on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/finish06/pyunifi), which contains some helpful examples which may have helped you to discover the proper use for the methods you've leveraged here.

Other than these considerations, your code looks fine. When you rectify these issues, you'll have a script that would look somewhat like the following

```
from pyunifi.controller import Controller

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--controller', default='192.168.0.2', help='the controller address (default "unifi")')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', default='apiadmin', help='the controller username (default("admin")')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', default='apipass', help='the controller password')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--port', default='8443', help='the controller port (default "8443")')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', default='v5', help='the controller base version (default "v5")')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--siteid', default='default', help='the site ID, UniFi >=3.x only (default "default")')
parser.add_argument('-V', '--no-ssl-verify', default=False, action='store_true', help='Don\'t verify ssl certificates')
parser.add_argument('-C', '--certificate', default='', help='verify with ssl certificate pem file')
args = parser.parse_args()

ssl_verify = False

if ssl_verify and len(args.certificate) > 0:
    ssl_verify = False 
        
c = Controller(args.controller, args.username, args.password, args.port, args.version, args.siteid, ssl_verify=ssl_verify)

for client in c.get_clients(): # loop over each client returned from get_clients()
    print(client['mac'])
```

Comment: Thank you esqew that works, just out of interest if I specify any ther parameters in the ```print(client['mac'])``` for example hostname instead of mac would that do the same? Just having a play around to see what data I can get out so thought would give hostname a shot but get a KeyError.

Comment: @dansmith The answer to your follow-up will entirely depend on what your `pyunifi` library returns as part of its `Client` object. I'm not so familiar with the library and its return values; you might consider consulting the documentation I linked in my answer or instead doing a `print(client)` to dump the entire object definition to see what keys are available.